Google chrome crashes
Google Chrome Version 127.0.6533.88 (Official Build) (64-bit) crashes after approximately 1 minute.
No error messages.

Update from comments:
I am running Ubuntu 24.04. I deleted Chrome following graham's link then reinstalled and the same problem persists. Chrome simply closes after running for one minute without error messages.

Good question to ask Chrome Support

how was Chrome installed? This Ubuntu Handbook article explains the process

I am running Ubuntu 24.04. I deleted Chrome following graham's link then reinstalled and the same problem persists. Chrome simply closes after running for one minute without error messages. How can I check for logs or error messages?

Google Chrome errors
Since you reinstalled but the problem still exists, it might be due to your profile.
Open a terminal and enter:
cp -r ~/.config/google-chrome ~/.config/google-chrome.old ---This will copy your chrome profile to google-chrome.old.
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome ---This will remove the chrome profile.
Then start chrome.
Your old profile is in .config in your home directory, if you do not need it you can simply delete it.

$ cp ~/.config/google-chrome ~/.config/google-chrome.old
cp: -r not specified; omitting directory '/home/rui/.config/google-chrome'
rui@rui-HP-EliteBook-8530p:~$ rm rf ~~/.config/google-chrome
rm: cannot remove 'rf': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove '~~/.config/google-chrome': No such file or directory

that is the response.

Sorry there was some mistakes in the answer, it is ok now, try it again with the commands in the answer.

and please read https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

I am sorry Amar. I am a complete beginner in Ubuntu.

cp: error copying '/home/rui/.config/google-chrome/BrowserMetrics/BrowserMetrics-66AD3C0A-58BF.pma' to '/home/rui/.config/google-chrome.old/BrowserMetrics/BrowserMetrics-66AD3C0A-58BF.pma': Input/output error

Try df -h and edit your question (it is on the bottom of your question) with the results do not write it in comments, and read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools you may have a hard drive problem.
